# Position vertical line through other lines

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with vertical line between two divs.

[image: desired result]

My code:
[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdxLw265/)

```
.one, .two{
width: 100%;
display:block;
height:200px;
```

}

If I put border right or left that's not gonna help me to solve my problem.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the horizontal rule tag to create vertical lines. `<hr width="1" size="500">` By using minimal width and large size, horizontal rule becomes a vertical one.

Comment: @eclipsis but how to put it in front of those two lines? z-index?

Comment: I'll create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the horizontal rule tag to create vertical lines: `<hr width="1" size="500">`, plus `position: absolute` to control where the line goes. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbg9ass1/).

You'll have to adjust the top, right, bottom, and left values relative to your layout.